# CRM 2011 and SSRS - Generating a report for a single record

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it at all possible using CRM 2011 and SSRS to generate a report on a single record, and only get results for that one record?

***EDIT***
Additional Info - Must Use:
Custom SSRS report
Custom entity in CRM

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more specific link to your question: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/03/18/parameterizing-fetch-based-reports.aspx). You're probably looking for pre-filtering (look for "3. Pre-filtering Element" in the link provided) if you want the report to be record specific (context sensitive).

Here's a link describing the 2 types of pre-filters (CRM 4.0 but the theory applies to CRM 2011): [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/11/13/using-data-pre-filtering-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-reports.aspx). And here's an example of prefiltering in CRM 2011: [link](http://fetchxml.blogspot.com/2011/05/fetchxml-crm-2011-pre-filtering.html)

I have done this successfully in CRM 2011 with a completely custom report made in BIDS, on a custom entity, with full context sensitivity.

Make sure to learn fetchXML as it's going to be the going forward technology for these reports. The existing reports are using SQL which make them bad examples to copy off of.

Here's an example on how to extract fetchXML from an advanced find: [link](http://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/axtechnical/b/axfortechies/archive/2011/04/14/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-fetch-xml-based-custom-reports.aspx) It also has more information on pre-filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a the report `Account Overview.rdl`. It could be executed for a single account record or multiple records.

See [Reporting for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Using Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097.aspx)

Comment: This is with a custom SSRS report, though, mandated by the project requirements, and a custom entity.  Would this still be able to be worked/modified to work with the custom entity and the requirements of the project?

Comment: You could use this report as a sample for your own which targets your specific entity.

Comment: Account Overview.rdl is a bad example since the reports in 2011 and on are going to be fetch XML.

Comment: @RyanonRails Nope. 2011 introduced Fetch-based reports in addition to SQL-based reports. However they are only a **must** for CRM Online. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097.aspx

Comment: Sorry, my comment made it seem like it only supported fetchXML. I meant to say CRM 2011 is starting to suggest fetchXML more than before. Specially since it works in both environments.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an embedded connection to the CRM database engine for the environment you want to target.
2. Create an embedded dataset to query the current record. This going to be kind of weird since experience will tell you that you are going to get tons of records, but because of the clunkiness behind CRM it will actually only get the current record. For example, if you wanted to get the current quote you would use "`SELECT quoteid FROM FilteredQuote AS CRMAF_Quote`"
3. Add a parameter to store the reference to the entity you just queried. In keeping with this example I created `@QuoteFilter` which is type text, could store multiple values (even though that's not what we're using it for), and gets its default value from the dataset in step 2. Also, probably ought to make this hidden since GUIDs aren't end user friendly.
4. Finally, use the parameter discovered in the where clause of the other datasets. For example, a search on quote products for the current quote would look something like `SELECT * FROM FilteredQuoteDetail WHERE (quoteid = @QuoteFilter)`

As a final note, you should keep in mind that CRM loves to remember everything even when you don't want it, too. On one of my reports I messed up my datasource and CRM was forever convinced that the report should run against all records. I fixed my datasource, but uploading the report did not trigger a refresh and correct the problem. In the end, I deleted the report from CRM, created a new one, uploaded the same exact file with no changes, and everything worked. Go figure.